# Enterprise Library 4.1 and .Net4

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, enterprise-library

I have a project that uses the Enterprise Library 4.1.  When I target .net 4 and compile, I get an error that says I need to add a reference to System.ServiceModel version 3.  My reference is to System.ServiceModel version 4.  How can I tell Visual Studio 2010 to reference a .net3 assembly from a .net3 project?  Or, does somebody have a workaround for this issue?

I am using the RTM version of VS2010

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some references in the csproj file (e.g. System.ServiceModel in ExceptionHandling.WCF project) have the SpecificVersion property set to True.

You can right click on this reference and choose Properties and change this value to False. Alternatively you can edit the csproj file in notepad and change `<SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion> to <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>` for this reference